# Kotlin Koans Comparison Exercise. Why does this solution not work?

Tags: kotlin

Just setting off on trying to learn some Kotlin I've read the official solution and understand it but this is what I came up with on my own first.

Question:

```
Learn about operator overloading and how the different conventions for operations like ==, <, + work in Kotlin. Add the function compareTo to the class MyDate to make it comparable. After this, the code below date1 < date2 should start to compile.

Note that when you override a member in Kotlin, the override modifier is mandatory.
```

My Answer:

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDate

data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) : Comparable<MyDate> {
    override fun compareTo(other: MyDate): Int {
        val dateA = LocalDate.of(this.year, this.month, this.dayOfMonth)
        val dateB = LocalDate.of(other.year, other.month, other.dayOfMonth)
        return Duration.between(dateA, dateB).toDays().toInt()
    }
}

fun test(date1: MyDate, date2: MyDate) {
    // this code should compile:
    println(date1 < date2)
}
```

I went at this thinking I would work out the difference between the two in days and just return it. but the error I get is "Unsupported unit: Seconds" What does this mean in this context. I believe I'm returning the correct type from compareTo as an int. What am I missing here?

This is the official solution for reference

```
data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int) : Comparable<MyDate> {
    override fun compareTo(other: MyDate) = when {
        year != other.year -> year - other.year
        month != other.month -> month - other.month
        else -> dayOfMonth - other.dayOfMonth
    }
}

fun test(date1: MyDate, date2: MyDate) {
    // this code should compile:
    println(date1 < date2)
}
```

Different approach but I would expect the tests to pass both ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Duration` is time based, and works with `Temporal`s that supports seconds. From [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)):

> The specified temporal objects must support the SECONDS unit. For full accuracy, either the NANOS unit or the NANO_OF_SECOND field should be supported.

`LocalDate` does not support seconds. You should instead use `Period.between`, or `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between`.

Another mistake is that you are comparing the dates in the reverse order of the official solution. `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateA, dateB).toInt()` would give a positive number if `dateA` (`this`) is before `dateB` (the parameter). If you look at the official solution, `compareTo` returns a positive number if `this` is after the parameter.

Therefore, you should do:

```
override fun compareTo(other: MyDate): Int {
    val dateA = LocalDate.of(this.year, this.month, this.dayOfMonth)
    val dateB = LocalDate.of(other.year, other.month, other.dayOfMonth)
    // note the switched order
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateB, dateA).toInt()
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Really good explanation